# Power shell script works fine in Windows power shell ISE, but it done't work in Power shell version 5

Tags: json, shell, powershell

I have following script it works fine in ISE. I can execute and debug this script by ISE.

```
    $file = "backup_settings.json";
    class JsonParser
    {
        $json = $null;
        $setting  = $null;
        $validJson = $false;
        $baseAddress = $null;

        JsonParser()
        {

        }

        ParseJson()
        {
            try 
            {
                $this.json = Get-Content -Raw $global:file; 
                $this.setting = ConvertFrom-Json $this.json -ErrorAction Stop;
                $this.validJson = $true;
            } 
            catch 
            {
                $this.validJson = $false;
            }

            if (-Not $this.validJson) 
            {
                Write-Host "Provided text is not a valid JSON string" -foregroundcolor "Red";
                return;
            }


            if($this.setting.baseAddress)
            {
                $this.baseAddress = $this.setting.baseAddress;
                Write-Host $this.baseAddress;
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "No valid baseAddress provided setting file" -foregroundcolor "Red";
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    $json = [JsonParser]::new(); 
    $json.ParseJson();
```

But in PowerShell version 5 the result is:-

> Provided text is not a valid JSON string

Note that I have backup_settings.json in the same directory. What could be the reason? How can I run this in power shell with correct result?

Updated code and result:-

I tried the following:-

```
    $file = (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "backup_settings.json")

    Write-Host $file;

    if([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($file))
    {
        Write-Host "Empty path"  
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "file  path: "$file;
    }

    if(Test-Path $file)
    {
        Write-Host "File exist" $file.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "file not found".
    }
    $json = [JsonParser]::new(); 
    $json.ParseJson();
```

Result:-

```
   C:\tools\backup_settings.json
  file  path:  C:\tools\backup_settings.json
  File exist C:\tools\backup_settings.json
  Provided text is not a valid JSON string
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Stepping through your code to see what's wrong? In the PowerShell console host you can still debug, using `Set-PSBreakpoint` (once at the debug prompt, type `h` to see help on how to step through).

Comment: I'm new in ps scripting. I don't know how to do it. I will try to google it. If you can suggest any link how to debug it as you suggest. It will be helpful.  It is very mysterious.

Comment: `$file` is not the same as `$global:file`; your `Parse()` method should be taking the file name as a parameter. If you want to test with the global first, then make sure you use `$global:file` every time you reference the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the path to your JSON file is not properly resolved when you're running it in powershell.  Add the following to see if that's the case:

```
Test-Path $global:file
```

If it prints out `False`, that would mean that your script is not able to find the json file. In that case, you should probably change the first line to something like this:

```
$file = (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "backup_settings.json")
```

Comment: Please check my updated code and result. It looks very mysterious.

Comment: I did it $file = (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "backup_settings.json"). Sorry, I forgot to update the  $this.json = Get-Content -Raw $global:file;  to $file. It is fine now